# Как заставить андроид выполнять определенный цикл действий в одном приложении

Tags: android

Имеется приложение на андроид. Нужно сделать так, чтобы телефон сам выполнял определенный алгоритм действий внутри этой программы. Всего 3-4 действия:

1. Кликнуть там
2. Кликнуть вот там
3. Кликнуть тут

Подскажите, как это всё сделать?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону инструментов автоматизированного тестирования UI.

Answer (score 2):

Espresso - https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html

UI Automator - https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator.html

Эти средства интеграционного тестирования позволят Вам имитировать действия пользователя.